# Cakephp 2.0 inflector slug text encoding utf 8 return unexpected string

Tags: utf-8, cakephp-2.1, slug

I have a problem with the `Inflector::slug();` function on my live server.
Local everything works fine.

I use the following code:

```
Inflector::slug($data['menu_items']['page_url'], '_');
```

A URL like `'this is an url'` outputs `'t_u_l'`.

It has probably something tod o with text-encoding, but I changed everything to UTF-8.

Anybody had this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Php have to be compiled with "--enable-unicode-properties" instead of utf-8

or/and

Sounds like your PCRE libraries are broken (this happens when the pcre libraries don't properly handle unicode patterns)